# PHP, IF Condition with NOT (!) operator and another set of parentheses

Tags: php, conditional-statements

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
if (!$var === true) {
```

or

```
if (!($var === true)) {
```

I came across some code like that, and trying to figure out it's use.

I get that conditions inside parentheses are evaluated from innermost outward.

Comment: some one is getting paid by the number of characters they type

Comment: `$var !== true` would be a better way to write this, with no operator precedence gotchas

Comment: If you had a dollar for everytime that's been asked also @Dagon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has to with PHP's [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

The `!` is evaluated *before* the `===` is.  So, in the 1st example:

1. Negate `$var`
2. Compare that value to `true`

In the 2nd example, you are using parentheses to force the `===` to happen first.  So, you get:

1. Compare `$var` to true
2. Negate the comparison

Since you are using `===` - which compares type and value - to compare to a boolean, these are *not quite* equivalent.

What if `$var = 5`?

1. `!$var === true` becomes `!5 === true`.  That's `0 === true`, which is `false`.
2. `!($var === true)` becomes `!(5 === true)`.  That's `!(false)`, which is `true`.

Note: When doing `!5` in the first example, the `5` is [converted to a boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), then negated (that's how `!` works).  There is no boolean conversion of the `5` in the second example since you are using `===`.

Note 2: The 2nd example is equivalent to `$var !== true`.

Answer (score 0):

If `$var` is a boolean or boolean-equivalent value, then the first code snippet will invert it and then compare. For example, if `$var = false`, the first snippet would evaluate to `if (true === true) { ... }`. The compared value itself is changed (not the variable value, but the value being used to compare).

This is opposed to the second code snippet, which inverts the result of the comparison. In the previous example, `true === true` results, obviously, in `true`. In the second snippet, if `$var = false` (as it was in the previous example), then `false === true` is false. However, we then negate the result of that comparison and get `false`.

The answers here are the same, but they are inherently calculated differently. I'm having a difficult time thinking of an example where the two result in separate answers. But what they are doing are two different operations.

As said before, though: the first example, `!$val` changes the value that is being used to compare against the `true`, whereas the second example, `!($val === true)` changes the result of the comparison between the two different values.